# Angular 2 search, open in new page

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a single page application and several routes.

I want to be able to do this:
When I seach I want my application to open the "/search" route and pass the values from the searchbox.

From there I was thinking that I'll get the values either from the querystring or what ever way is possible, and pass it to my http-request, and then present the result.

All of the info I have found is how to filter the search on the same page.

Can anyone help?

Comment: U can use `nested routing` or `pipe`

Comment: Could I use something like this:
{ path: '/search/:query', component: Search, name: 'Search' }, Use the input value as a variable, and on search <a [routerLink]="['./search, inputvariable]">

Comment: Yes you may use that. but it is not a efficient way.

Comment: Do you have any example then how I could do it, or any reference?